# Can't open two monitors on Teamviewer 11

Tags: teamviewer

Ever since the version 11 update, I've not been able to open a second nor third monitor from the view menu. It opens a new tab in the window bar and both tabs are completely frozen afterwards -- until I close either tab and everything works again.

This used to work before without a hitch.

I'm using Teamviewer to connect from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 14.04, both have the latest available Teamviewer versions and the problem has now persisted for many months.

Edit: Changing monitor from the monitor button works tho, but I have 3 monitors here and @ remote location and it would be preferable to be able to open them all at once, like I used to be.